# how to change csv file by condition in for loop using pandas in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

this is the code that i'm using to do this, but i know that this is bad and it can be done in for loop:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',')
if "c[1]=2" in text:
 df.loc[df.id==1,'r']=254
 df.loc[df.id==1,'g']=0
 df.loc[df.id==1,'b']=0
else:
  if "c[2]=3" in text:
    df.loc[df.id==2,'r']=254
    df.loc[df.id==2,'g']=0
    df.loc[df.id==2,'b']=0
  else:
     if "c[3]=4" in text:
       df.loc[df.id==3,'r']=254
       df.loc[df.id==3,'g']=0
       df.loc[df.id==3,'b']=0
```

....

until:

```
if "c[34]=35" in text:
  df.loc[df.id==34,'r']=254
  df.loc[df.id==34,'g']=0
  df.loc[df.id==34,'b']=0
else: #this is the final else
  df.r=0
  df.g=254
  df.r=0
df.to_csv("file.csv",index=False, sep=',')
```

i can't do this if i have more and more indexes.
this is all about to change values in csv using python and with conditions.
can it be done in loop ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 35 as maximum

```
for i in range(1,35)
    if "c["+str(i)+"="+str(i+1) in text:
        df.loc[df.id==i+1,'r']=254
        df.loc[df.id==i+1,'g']=0
        df.loc[df.id==i+1,'b']=0
    else : 
        df.r=0
        df.g=254
        df.r=0
```

Comment: thank you Mayeul sgc, but i think this is not working cause the else is going to change all values in the final step of the loop.

Comment: I did the same else statement as the one in your code, it access the else only the line is not in text, but it modifies everything indeed. Do you mean that you change all the other line to the generic values you put ?

Comment: in the last loop, if the statement is not True it's going to change all the columns of the file. the default values are r=0,g=254,b=0 in every line. if the condition in every line is True the values must be r=254,g=0,b=0 .

Comment: i think i can do this: first: df.r=0 df.g=254 df.b=0 then do the for loop as you did Mayeul sgc without the else.